# Using a Silverlight Hyperlink Button Style without the Navigation

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

In my page I want the button that looks like the HyperlinkButton (underline when MouseOver etc).  But I want to handle the navigation in code (by using the Click event handler).  So I'm using a HyperlinkButton and setting the NavigateUri to an empty string and setting the Click handler.

But the problem is that the browser tried to download the entire .xbap as a file download, presumably the empty NavigateUri mean "root".

Is there any way I can re-use the HyperLinkButton class (for visuals) but perform the actual navigation / or action in the Click method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Open expression blend.
2. Right click on hyperlink button -> Edit style -> Edit copy
3. Change TargetType="HyperlinkButton" to TargetType="Button"
4. Use this style with any button.

Also, I have no problem with code

```
<HyperlinkButton Content="HyperlinkButton" Click="hb_Click"/>
```

Comment: That code is what I have in my project and it's no working. ;>

Comment: Ok, download expression blend.

Comment: @will: vorrtex is correct. If you have no NavigateUri property at all **(not an *empty* string)** it will not navigate and you can simply add a click handler.

Comment: OK, removing the NavigateUri property worked.  Thanks guys, v much appreciated.